# Python Splitting Line for AlphaNumeric Substrings Only

Tags: python, string, split

I want to split a line into it's substrings but I don't want to include semicolons. How can I do this and ignore all semicolons?

For example, if the string is like:

```
ignore the last semicolon;
ignore this last semicolon too ; (yes the space is intentional)
```

I want to return something like:

```
['ignore','the','last','semicolon'] or
['ignore','the','last','semicolon;'] or
['ignore the last semicolon',';']
```

Any tips on this?

Comment: Please share what have you done so far. It's not a homework solving portal. :)

Comment: You have listed 3 different things to return. Which one exactly do you want?

Comment: I'm not at all clear what you want; you've given three rather different results.  How does *any* of these "ignore" semicolons?  The first one simply drops the semicolon, which you can handle with `replace`.  The other two give distinctly different results; the first is the default operation of `split`; the second is possible with `regex`.  Please post your needs and the coding attempt that's giving you trouble.

Comment: @NVSAbhilash It is not homework. I am learning Python on my own and have been practicing string manipulation but this is one thing I do not know how to go about.

Comment: @Prune @izhang If I just do split on the sentence, it will return `['ignore','the','last','semicolon',';']`as there might be a space before the semicolon and I don't want that as the last element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string is text you can first use text_without_semicolon = text.replace(‘;’, ‘’) and then use text_without_semicolon.split(‘ ‘) this will give you the first output that you wanted.